# How to remove enter in oracle utf file

Tags: oracle, plsql

The problem is to remove enter and join in one line for ': 86:', which lasts until ': 61:'

http://wklejto.pl/840401

Comment: Please add your code directly to the question and not as link to some web site.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to see how to formulate a good question to get a good answer?

Answer (score -1):

```
   :86:770 PRZELEW KRAJOWY SP; Z RACH.: 78105000861000309030383012; OD: 
DOZ SPÓŁKA AKCYJNA DIRECT SPÓŁKA KOMANDYTOWA KINGA C.GILLETTE 11 
94-406 ŁÓD¬; TYT.: 
/VAT/10655,40/IDC/6252315798/INV/FV/334/PL/2001/TXT/FAKTURA; 
DATA STEMPLA: 30.04.2020; TNR: 191181084638228.280001
:61:2005040504DN12655,40NTRFNONREF//EL011880-016890
368-PODATEK VAT
```